# Last table column is wider

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I have made a table but when I view it the last table column is wider than the other ones. Anyone able to help me out tell me why this is happening?

Have tried shortening the entire table width but that hasn't helped. Must be something I am missing. Thankyou.

Here is my code,

```
<table class="TFtable" style="height: 448px;" width="1007">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #000000;">
<p><span style="font-size: 200%; color: #749d36;">    Pricing</span></p>
<br />
<p><span style="font-size: 200%;">     Structure</span></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">Professional</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume</span></strong></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #749d36;">$199</span></p>
</td>
<td class="green_background" style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium; color: #000000;">Managerial</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium; color: #000000;">Resume</span></strong></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large;">$299</span></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">Executive</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume</span></strong></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #749d36;">$399</span></p>
</td>
<td class="green_background" style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium; color: #000000;">C-Suite</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium; color: #000000;">Resume</span></strong></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large;">$499</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume Specs</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: small;">2-3 pg resume</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">4-5 pg resume</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ cover sheet and</p>
<p>graphics</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">+ standalone bio pg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Phone Interview</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Draft To Approve</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Template Options</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
<p><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Extras</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ free LinkedIn</p>
<p>profile</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ free LinkedIn</p>
<p>profile</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Delivery</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Cover Letter</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #000000; text-align: center;">
<p>If you're not sure where</p>
<p>your job would fit, please</p>
<p>get in touch to discuss</p>
<p>your requirements.</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Vocations (such as</p>
<p>Teaching &amp; Nursing)</p>
<p>Early Career Professionals</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Managers and Senior</p>
<p>Professionals (Lawyers,</p>
<p>Medical Doctors), BDMs,</p>
<p>Consultants...</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Senior Managers and Exec</p>
<p>Directors (Operations</p>
<p>Managers, GMs, Heads of</p>
<p>Department</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>CEOs, CFOs, COOs, CIOs,</p>
<p>Managing Directors, Board</p>
<p>Members &amp; Non-Execs,</p>
<p>Practice Directors &amp; Principals</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/xsmaLab3/ Added red to tr to check for width issues. I'm assuming there's some code modifying the last tr width on the page you're adding it to since you tagged this as joomla.

Comment: Yeah the last table column is wider than the others. How do i fix that?

Comment: Oh, table column. In your question you're asking about the last table row. Let me edit that for you.

Comment: Check my answer and hit the check mark if it solved your problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but is there anything preventing you from setting the width of the `td`s to a percentage? Your table has 5 columns, just do `td { width:20%; }` in CSS and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width for all of your table columns. Since you're using inline css, they should all look something like this:

```
<td style="width:200px;">
```

200px each since you have 5 and your table width is about 1000px.

Full table: http://jsfiddle.net/xsmaLab3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just set a width to the `td` in the CSS:

```
td { 
    width:20%; /* because there are 5 columns 100% / 5 = 20% */
}
```

And then the browser will work it for you. No need to set width to the `table` if you don't want to, and no need to do extra calculations or anything.

See it working with your code [here without setting the table width](http://jsfiddle.net/2zk5wf1h/), or [here with a table width](http://jsfiddle.net/2zk5wf1h/1/) (not recommended as the width attribute on the table element is obsolete in HTML5, and you should use CSS instead)